# NFS: mount above export-path possible

Tags: debian, nfs

I figured out that I am able to mount a path above my nfs export.

/etc/exports:

```
/home/max/shared      192.168.10.0/24(rw,sync,subtree_check)
```

This works and I can access the remote share.

```
mount 192.168.10.99:/ /mnt
```

But I expected that only a mount of the full path (/home/max/shared) would work.

NFS v4, Debian 9

Am I wrong or what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's nfs v3 and not v4? And there's no other export of /?

Comment: There is no other export. And it is NFS v4.

Comment: Check out section *Using exportfs with NFSv4* in this [guide](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-server-config-exports.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is normal for NFS 4 unless you specify a top-level root with option fsid=0

```
/home/max/shared 192.168.10.0/24(rw,sync,subtree_check,fsid=0)
```

may help

Or you could limit it to /home

```
/home 192.168.10.0/24(ro,sync,subtree_check,fsid=0)
/home/max/shared 192.168.10.0/24(rw,sync,subtree_check)
```

Though the problem is there that other /home/username directories will still be accessible at least read-only, so see below for what people do to really limit what is exported:

What people seem to do is create a new top-level directory , export it with fsid=0, and then use bind mounts to mount all their exports under that

eg

```
 mkdir -p /nfs/home/max/shared
 mount -o bind /home/max/shared /nfs/home/max/shared
```

And then export /nfs  with fsid=0

Comment: Added a note that with the first simple method, other home directories would still be exported too